# OpenCSV can't read InputStream created by Jersey2

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0, opencsv

I have the following code:

```
    @POST
    @Path("/csv")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public String populateCSV(@FormDataParam("data") InputStream fileInputStream) throws   JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        File initialFile = new File("/Users/me/Downloads/file.csv");
        InputStream targetStream = FileUtils.openInputStream(initialFile);
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(targetStream), ',', '"', 0);
        CSVReader jerseyReader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream), ',', '"', 0);
        List<String[]> fileAllRows = reader.readAll();
        List<String[]> jerseyAllRows = jerseyReader.readAll();
        return null;
}
```

`jerseyAllRows` which is created out of `CSVReader` that reads Jersey conversion of File to InputStream returns empty lines, while `fileAllRows` which is created out of a `FileInputStream` that contains the same file that is being submitted to jersey, returns 3 lines.

What makes the way that Jersey2 reads file create a different InputStream?

I need to post a file to Jersey2 and be able to parse it with OpenCSV

**EDITED**

If I convert the jersey input stream into String like this:

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(IOUtils.toString(inputStream).getBytes());
reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(is), ',', '"', 0);
```

I do get lines. but that's a waste of memory :( Any idea?

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: no. I don't get any error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you should try [uniVocity-parsers](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers) CSV parser as it is twice as fast and has many additional features.

Sencond, you should provide the encoding of your input.

Third, you may also need to specify the line separators explicitly

Example using [uniVocity-parsers](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers):

```
File initialFile = new File("/Users/me/Downloads/file.csv");
InputStream targetStream = FileUtils.openInputStream(initialFile);

CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
settings.getFormat().setLineSeparator("\n");

CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
List<String[]> allRows = parser.parseAll(new InputStreamReader(targetStream, "UTF-8"));
```

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).

Comment: great. this worked! can I write with this parser? I want to add to that existing file that I am reading another column

Comment: Yes you can! Simply use the [CsvWriter](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers/blob/master/src/main/java/com/univocity/parsers/csv/CsvWriter.java) class. Check the [tutorial](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers/#quick-and-simple-csv-writing-example)

Comment: Thanks. what is the outputWrite? I tried to send a ByteArrayOutputStream but it didn't accept it

Comment: Just provide a Writer:ByteArrayOutputStream csvResult = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(csvResult, "UTF-8"); CsvWriter csvWriter = new CsvWriter(writer, settings);